# Send array of objects to RESTful API

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

How can I send an array (a set of simular items) in a POST request to a RESTful API build with Codeigniter?

I can send singular items like this:

```
name=John&email=demo@demo.com
```

But how can I send items like this and use them on the server side like an array?

```
keywords=blue,sky,weather,car,vacation
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could send a [json](http://www.json.org/) array depending on the capabilities of the backend. If the RESTful API consumes this content type you are able to then send an array by simply POSTing to the RESTful path, using the json array as the payload.

One way to send the payload would be with jQuery / AJAX:

```
.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonArray)
});
```

Comment: I am using Phils RESTserver and Codeigniter. I would love to use JSON but think I am stuck with normal POST data. Is it possible to send and array with that?

Comment: Refer to http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/ which is posted on philsturgeon's github. The "The URL's" section explains:

"... out of the box your REST API can use:
json – useful for JavaScript and increasingly PHP apps."

Comment: I have changed my original post to reflect a possible way to send the payload using jQuery / AJAX.

Comment: Thank you. How can I process these details on the server using Phils restserver?

Comment: It seems that if you follow the tutorial I have previously posted, it explains how to create the backend RESTful API paths. What would you like to do with the JSON Array on the backend?

Comment: contentType: "application/json" the most important part. worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to send it in JSON?

```
{"keywords" : ["blue","sky","weather","car","vacation"]}
```

Comment: I am using Phils RESTserver and Codeigniter. I would love to use JSON but think I am stuck with normal POST data. Is it possible to send and array with normal POST data?

Comment: @Jon, sorry, being not familiar with PHP and codeigniter, I give up here. You sure codeigniter can't handle JSON? http://codeigniter.com/wiki/JSON_Helper/ OK, I'm not sure when you get "Request-URI Too Long" error, but maybe you can try to build an URI like this "keywords=blue,sky,weather,car,vacation" http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Comment: I can send in this: query=("email@example.com","anna@nicole.com") or your example above but how can I loop through each item in PHP?